# Sharepoint Web Services Item Data (access to "Created By" Column)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sharepoint

I am currently working on an application that displays the data of a Sharepoint calendar via Sharepoint Webservices. Therefore, I am using the List Service of the calendar.

I manage to get all important information except user data, such as *Created By* or *Modified By*. The XML which is returned contains the following:

```
<rs:data ItemCount="1" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset">
   <z:row ows_fRecurrence="0" ows_Attachments="0" ows_WorkspaceLink="0" ows_LinkTitle="Element1" ows_Location="ABG" ows_EventDate="2010-10-08 15:00:00" ows_EndDate="2010-10-08 15:00:00" ows_fAllDayEvent="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Title="Element1" ows_ID="1" ows_owshiddenversion="2" ows_UniqueId="1;#{CF790A42-0B9F-44FE-BAC5-5FE959C9BF1B}" ows_FSObjType="1;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="1;#2010-10-22 14:16:58" ows_Created="2010-10-22 14:16:58" ows_FileLeafRef="1;#1_.000" ows_FileRef="1;#*******/Test/Lists/TestCalendar/1_.000" ows_MetaInfo="1;#" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</rs:data>
```

I cannot see any indication where the information of the Author of that element is saved.

I tried to specify the ViewFields for my Query which didn't change anything. Also, I tried to add a custom column in the calendar that should contain Author information, but it didn't work at all.

This is my code to get the items:

```
****.Lists listService = new ****.Lists();
listService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
XmlNode activeItemData = listService.GetListItems(listGUID, activeItemViewGUID, null, null , "", null, "");
```

It would be amazing if someone could give me an indication what I could try to get the information I need.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I face the same problem with a regular DocLib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve the problem. If someone else is interested:

You need to specify another View of the Sharepoint Calendar and include the attributes you need as columns. If you take the GUID of that view as parameter in your GetLists-Method, you get the results you wish.

Sounds easy but still took me a hole day to figure out :O